# Iterating certain variables in a predefined function

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, code-request

I have a function which is dependent on a number of variables. I need to evaluate this function at the particular locations given by,

```
centroidList = Flatten[Table[{a, (i*π)/mm, (j*L)/(2*nn)}, {i, 1, 2*mm, 2}, {j, 1, 2*nn}], 1];
```

These locations are given in cylindrical coordinates and I wish for my function to be evaluated at each of these locations. The final output would be a n x 1 matrix which contains the evaluated function at the n locations generated by centroidList[ ].

A simplified version of the function which I wish to evaluate is,

```
c10[m_, n_, θ_, z_, F3_, b_] := (F3*Sin[m*π*z]*Cos[n*(θ - b)]);
```

Where; m, n, F3 and b are variables which I will define at the beginning of the notebook and θ and z are the Theta and z coordinates of each location given by centroidList.

The best I have been able to do so far is,

```
a = 0.1096; nn = 1; mm = 4; L = 1.408; co = 343; ω = 500; ko =ω/co; m = 1; n = 1; F3 = 100; b = π/4;

c11[m_, n_, θ_, z_, F3_, b_] := (F3*Sin[m*π*z]*Cos[n*(θ - b)]);
centroidList = Flatten[Table[{a, (i*π)/mm, (j*L)/(2*nn)}, {i, 1, 2*mm, 2}, {j, 
 1, 2*nn}], 1];
cT[{a2_, a3_}] := c11[m, n, a2, a3, F3, b];

Table[cT[centroidList[[i]], centroidList[[j]]], {i, 1, Length[centroidList], 2}, {j, 1, Length[centroidList], 2}] // MatrixForm
```

However, this does not produce the correct size matrix and also fails to evaluate the function properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your last two lines to:

```
cT[{_, a2_, a3_}] := c11[m, n, a2, a3, F3, b];
cT /@ centroidList

(*{80.1567, -95.8522, 0., 0., -80.1567, 95.8522, 0., 0.}*)
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes that does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @ElHeatho From the above `c11[m, n, #2, #3, F3, b] & @@@ centroidList` would also work.  See the [Pure Functions tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).